# TCP -- partial segments in receiver's sliding window

Tags: tcp, sliding-window

[RFC793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) states that, at the receiver, the incoming segment is accepted upon the following check:

> The first part of this test checks to see if the beginning of the segment
> falls in the window, the second part of the test checks to see if the end of
> the segment falls in the window; if the segment passes either part of the
> test it contains data in the window.

However, there may be a case that the the beginning of the segment falls in the window, but the end of the segment doesn't. This is he case when there still is room in the window, but the segment size is longer than the remaining space in the buffer. What if this is the case-- what happens?

Does TCP drop this segment? or Does it arrange the buffer based on Maximum Segment Size so that it can take these partial segments?

TIA.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code, and do use quote formatting for text that is quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the sender will not send more data than the receiver can accept in its window, as the current window size is sent on each TCP header. If the receiver's window is filling, it will send a lower window size value, so the sender will know how much data the receiver can accept until it fills.